# Array formula sum column

Tags: google-sheets

Any one can help me, I have thousand column need formula to count.

```
   A         B       C          B
1,000.00    50.00   0.00      100    
1,000.00    -       50.00     100 
1,000.00    50.00     - 
1,000.00    -       25.00     50
```

Any body know how to array this formula

```
=ifs(or(D2="-",D2=""),"",C2<>"-",D2+A2-C2,C2="-",D2+A2-B2)
```

[Sample spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lnPXrnECf7ARmqNkJjMWsrp2IbJ5IdroKxVHzgIhEBo/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: you need to format your question, and specify whether you're working in Google sheets or Excel

Answer (score 2):

For an array formula, you need to pass an array of cells. For example, rather than `D2`, use `D2:D`.

The `OR()` statement will cause issues, so you need to reformat it using [bracket notation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en) to create a new range for the single condition field and [`+`](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-7/boolean-arithmetic/) for the OR.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFS({(D2:D="-")+(D2:D="")},"",C2:C<>"-",D2:D+A2:A-C2:C,C2:C="-",D2:D+A2:A-B2:B))
```

Comment: My pleasure @npwopis Please consider marking the question as answered